# How can I search a string from a string array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I have a string `'a'` and want all results which have `'a'` string array.

```
var searchquery = 'a';
var list = [temple,animal,game,match, add];
```

I want `result = [animal,game,match,add];` all elements which have `'a'` as a part of their name.how can I achieve that ?

Comment: using `regex` would be an overkill for this simple problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the list:

```
var searchquery = 'a';
var list = ['temple', 'animal', 'game', 'match', 'add'];
var results = list.filter(function(item) {
    return item.indexOf(searchquery) >= 0;
});
// results will be ['animal', 'game', 'match', 'add']
```

(Note that you need to quote the strings in the `list` array.)

Comment: Snap! :) Extra time required for fiddling :P

Comment: @pandit - I don't think a regex would buy you anything in terms of performance or clarity of code. Since `searchquery` is a variable, quite the opposite, I would think. Also, I added a link to documentation for the `filter` function.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="display"></div>

var searchquery = 'a';
var list = ["temple", "animal", "game", "match", "add"];
var results = list.filter(function(item) {
    return item.indexOf(searchquery) >= 0;
});

document.getElementById("display").textContent = results.toString();
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmywG/)